# Make visible a section while selection of an item from a select dropdown in Angular6 template

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, angular6

I have a requirement where when i select from a dropdown a section has to be made visible, and for now all the dropdown's have the same section to be displayed.
Issue is the first time when i select the item from the dropdown the section that i want is visible, but the second time i happen to select the section goes off, i want to keep the section visible on selection of any item from my dropdown.
Attaching my code trial below

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 m-form__group-sub">
                                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                                            <mat-label> Insurance Company Name</mat-label>
                                            <mat-select placeholder="Select" formControlName="inc_name"
                                                (selectionChange)="onSelecetionChange($event.value)">
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let policyComp of policyinc.data"
                                                    [value]="policyComp.inc_code">
                                                    {{ policyComp.inc_name }}</mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>
```

And here the component where i have the function

```
policyComp: boolean = false;


onSelecetionChange(value: string) {

    this.policyComp = !this.policyComp;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this method

```
onSelecetionChange(value: string) {
    this.policyComp = true;
}
```